# Geth's fast syncing cannot get past block 4179789

Tags: go-ethereum

I have been syncing my node using "geth console --fast" but it has been stuck at block 4179789 for a long time. It keeps importing new state entries. What's the problem here?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Update: I found out that the sync will get very slow at the end, since the last 1024 blocks will be verified thoroughly. According to BokkyPooBah's answer below, there are ~20M state entries to sync from start to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to leave your computer to sync until `knownStates` is complete, currently around 20+ million states.

### Details

I fast synced my `geth` node on a virtual host a few days ago to reduce the disk space usage. Following is the start of the synching process:

```
Aug 16 01:17:05 GethNode01 systemd[1]: Started Geth.
Aug 16 01:17:05 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:05] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.7-stable-ab5646c5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
Aug 16 01:17:05 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:05] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/beef/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
Aug 16 01:17:05 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:05] Writing default main-net genesis block
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Metropolis: 9223372036854775807 Engine: ethash}"
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/beef/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/beef/.ethash               count=2
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: WARN [08-16|01:17:06] Upgrading db log bloom bins
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Bloom-bin upgrade completed              elapsed=79.081µs
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
Aug 16 01:17:06 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:06] Starting P2P networking
Aug 16 01:17:08 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:08] UDP listener up                          self=enode://7624bc015762e52bd350810a3768aad6d65e81dcf4222f29fb9f43d8c0c0ea8cd7c889728d1fea18760903df8cda7bf07aecad89e4a793e6344de07bb53f94f5@[::]:30303
Aug 16 01:17:08 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:08] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://7624bc015762e52bd350810a3768aad6d65e81dcf4222f29fb9f43d8c0c0ea8cd7c889728d1fea18760903df8cda7bf07aecad89e4a793e6344de07bb53f94f5@[::]:30303
Aug 16 01:17:08 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:08] IPC endpoint opened: /home/beef/.ethereum/geth.ipc
Aug 16 01:17:08 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:08] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545
Aug 16 01:17:13 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:13] Block synchronisation started
Aug 16 01:17:16 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:16] Imported new state entries               count=1 flushed=0 elapsed=315.946µs processed=1 pending=17 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
Aug 16 01:17:16 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:16] Imported new state entries               count=16 flushed=0 elapsed=2.003ms   processed=17 pending=273 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
Aug 16 01:17:18 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:18] Imported new state entries               count=256 flushed=0 elapsed=37.702ms  processed=273 pending=4369 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
Aug 16 01:17:18 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:18] Imported new state entries               count=2   flushed=0 elapsed=371.457µs processed=275 pending=4401 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
Aug 16 01:17:18 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|01:17:18] Imported new state entries               count=2   flushed=0 elapsed=427.094µs processed=277 pending=4433 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
```

Following is the end of the fast syncing process 4 hours and 10 minutes later, show that there were **19,633,962** state entries then:

```
Aug 16 04:27:27 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:27] Imported new state entries               count=2    flushed=1    elapsed=11.411ms  processed=19633957 pending=24     retry=0    duplicate=3456 unexpected=13166
Aug 16 04:27:27 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:27] Imported new state entries               count=1    flushed=4    elapsed=6.913ms   processed=19633958 pending=20     retry=0    duplicate=3456 unexpected=13166
Aug 16 04:27:27 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:27] Imported new state entries               count=1    flushed=6    elapsed=223.668µs processed=19633959 pending=14     retry=0    duplicate=3456 unexpected=13166
Aug 16 04:27:30 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:30] Imported new state entries               count=2    flushed=3    elapsed=6.140ms   processed=19633961 pending=12     retry=0    duplicate=3456 unexpected=13166
Aug 16 04:27:30 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:30] Imported new state entries               count=1    flushed=12   elapsed=277.963µs processed=19633962 pending=0      retry=0    duplicate=3456 unexpected=13166
Aug 16 04:27:30 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:30] Imported new block receipts              count=1    elapsed=11.176ms  number=4161593 hash=e982cd…71c075 ignored=0
Aug 16 04:27:30 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:30] Committed new head block                 number=4161593 hash=e982cd…71c075
Aug 16 04:27:40 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:40] Imported new chain segment               blocks=9 txs=1075 mgas=50.943 elapsed=9.553s    mgasps=5.332 number=4161602 hash=3fb838…250571
Aug 16 04:27:48 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:48] Imported new chain segment               blocks=12 txs=1069 mgas=61.217 elapsed=8.357s    mgasps=7.325 number=4161614 hash=20d39c…ec2034
Aug 16 04:27:57 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:27:57] Imported new chain segment               blocks=10 txs=1163 mgas=61.370 elapsed=8.748s    mgasps=7.015 number=4161624 hash=4c45ab…e51633
Aug 16 04:28:05 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:28:05] Imported new chain segment               blocks=12 txs=1065 mgas=76.976 elapsed=8.560s    mgasps=8.992 number=4161636 hash=a50c2e…b2a50d
Aug 16 04:28:15 GethNode01 geth[551]: INFO [08-16|04:28:15] Imported new chain segment               blocks=7  txs=1136 mgas=45.996 elapsed=9.921s    mgasps=4.636 number=4161643 hash=ef9d31…33fc3e
```

In my home network, on a notebook with a solid state drive, this process can take more than a day.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I need to be more patient. The sync will get very slow at the end since the last 1024 blocks will be checked thoroughly as if it's a full sync.

Comment: If you stop Geth (or it crashes), and restart it knownStates and pulledStates are reset to 0. Does this mean Geth has to reimport all state entries?

Comment: Yup, from what I understand.

Comment: Where do you get the number 20M+? My `pulledStates` currently shows `1018284` and I am trying to get an idea of how far it needs to go.